# openWRT: create a web socket

Tags: websocket, openwrt

I need to create an auto-start app on the openWRT router which creates persistent web socket connection to a server with public ip. Anyone knows which module can do this ?

Comment: Have you checked https://libwebsockets.org/ ?

Comment: there also: https://github.com/darcyg/websocket-openwrt-client and http://www.pezzino.ch/websockets-demo/